# Another Rebus Puzzle By Me!

Tags: rebus

Just gonna make another Rebus Puzzle :)

[image]

Looking for a phrase here!

Comment: Cats armed with knives that think a lot

Comment: Not really :) @Duck

Comment: (Side note, please try to make the rebus be seen without scrolling.)

Comment: Can you make another one?

Comment: @u_ndefined I really don't know how to do that. Can u please edit it for me so that I can do so in future puzzles :)

Comment: Currently out of ideas but will try :) @Duck

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the phrase you're aiming at is:

> Curiosity killed the cat

Comment: How did I not get that!!!

Comment: Correct Answer! I knew I made it too obvious (for you) :)

Answer (score 4):

> **which (f)stab** and **which cat** ? Maybe it's a rebus that belongs in Unix stackexchange ;-)

Comment: +1 This answer in turn should be migrated to Humor SE (once it is created)!

Comment: @CiaPan There is a Humor Stack Exchange??? No way! :P